# Slow web response on first request

Tags: apache

I have a website, deployed on 2 identically configured servers - Ubuntu 14.04 / apache2 / MySQL / php. One is in a VM, the other is a physical box. Both servers behave the same.

The first request to go to a web page times out when sent from inside the **local network**, but responds fine from outside. So if I click on a link or a menu item on the web page, or call up a web page from a browser it times out. If then make a request for a web page it responds immediately and on all subsequent request, unless I leave it alone for over 20 seconds, then the next response will time out. If I click on one link, then wait 2 or 3 seconds, then click on the same or another link it responds. If I click a link, then click a link in another browser after 2 or 3 seconds it responds instantly.

My router is set up to redirect links from outside to the same server. When I make a request to the public address remotely it always responds instantly - no latency. This shows it's not the disk, or application pools or whatever else may take some time to spin up, it's something to do with accessing it locally. The same thing also happens with telnet, MySQL workbench and ftp with both machines. Nothing unusual in the apache logs, it seems the first request just doesn't get there.

I think it's probably my network config. I have a reason for the Ubuntu servers to be on a separate subnet, but I'm currently combining them. The servers are static IPs at 192.168.0.10 and 11, with a mask of 255.255.254.0.
I'm accessing them from machines in the 192.168.1.xx network, also with a mask of 255.255.254.0. Pings seems to go both ways instantly. It's really frustrating trying to test web updates when firstly the ftp has to be done twice and then the clicks have to be done twice if I leave it more than 20s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not many views of the question so probably nobody is interested anyway, but I found the answer.

I had a VMware virtual network set up at 192.168.0.0 for when I'm on a train (or at least not at home) so that I can communicate with my VM server by connecting the VM network adapter with the virtual network instead, preserving the static IP address. Even when I have the VM connected directly to the home network, the virtual network is still active on the PC which meant there are 2 separate networks in that range which obviously confuses things and takes a while to sort out. I guess it has to wait for one to time out before trying the other. Anyway, disabling the VMware virtual network when I'm at home sorts out the problem.